# Conditional comment not working for IE < 10 JSF

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to include a css file with a conditional comment when the browser is less than IE 10, but for some reason the file is not being included in the page. The site is built with JSF and I'm not allowed to use JavaScript.

```
    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <link href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/cn-dropdown.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hey @BalusC, Thanks you were right. I found the solution in the post you linked, but I wanted to ask you something 'cause I'm kinda noob here in stackoverflow. What should I do in this case? Delete my question or leave it marked as duplicate?

Comment: If you leave it, search engines will be happy with more keywords. If you delete it, you may contribute to a question ban if you have "too much" deleted questions.